# use get_theme_mod from all sites in network

Tags: multisite, theme-options

I'm creating a site that shows all sites in the network. Each site in the network has a theme customizer where a user enters text. I was able to get the name and url of the site but need to find a way to get the theme option from that site.

This is the code I'm using so far:

```
<?php $bcount = get_blog_count(); global $wpdb; $blogs = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->blogs WHERE spam = '0' AND deleted = '0' and archived = '0' and public='1'"));?>
<?php foreach($blogs as $blog) :?>
<?php if(!(($blog->blog_id == 1)&&($show_main != 1))):?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_blog_details($blog->blog_id)->siteurl; ?>"><?php echo get_blog_details($blog->blog_id)->blogname;?></a>
<?php endif;?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

I've also tried `get_template_part` but that didn't work

```
<?php echo get_template_part( 'twsa_show_about', get_blog_details($blog->blog_id)->blog_id );?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to switch to your blog using `switch_to_blog( $blog->blog_id );` and the access the data you want from that blog.

```
switch_to_blog( $blog->blog_id );
get_theme_mod('your_key');
```

This should give you customizer option data for that blog.

Also I'm not sure where you are using this code, but instead of using `wpdb` query you can use `get_sites` to get list of your sites.

See: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_sites/

Hope this is what you wanted.